# How to check if the parameters passed to function are correct

Tags: python, function

I have a list of args and a dict of kwargs

```
from myapp.tasks import my_function

def run_the_function():
    args = ['First', 'Last']
    kwargs = {'age': 30}
    correct_params = check_if_function_will_run() # how to do this?
    # if correct_params are present: run the function in async
    my_function.delay(*args, **kwargs)
    # else raise error
```

```
def my_function(first_name, last_name, email, age=None):
    # This is my function to be called in async manner
    # It will not run if above args and kwargs are passed to it.
```

I want to check whether the function will accept these parameters and will run. I thought of using following function:

```
from inspect import signature

def check_if_function_will_run(function, args, kwargs):
    actual_params_len = len(signature(function).parameters) # length of parameters accepted by function
    passed_params_len = len(args) + len(kwargs) # length of passed parameters
    return actual_params_len == passed_params_len # return if the length of passed and actual parameters is equal
```

But this approach lacks several cases like:

1. What is my_function has **kwargs in function definition?
2. if (actual_args != passed_args and actual_kwargs != passed_kwargs) but (actual_args + actual_kwargs) = (passed_args + passed_kwargs)
   These are some of the cases, there might be some cases missing on my side.

So, in the end is there a way to check if the function will accpet the passed args and kwargs, without actually running the function?

Comment: Calling a function without the correct number of arguments will raise a `TypeError`, you can just attempt to execute your function in a `try/except`.

Comment: What happens if the function fails? Can it be wrapped in try/except block with an exception processing as Python encourages better to try and fail rather than go through multiple preliminary checks?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting matter, I gotta say.

Couple of issues when trying this: first of all, every parameter can be passed as a kwarg, as long as it is not passed as an arg (meaning `my_func(1,age=7,email=12,last_name=2)` is perfectly valid, but `my_func(1,age=7,email=12,first_name=2)` is not because now the first arg and last kwarg should both be assigned to `first_name`).

In order to properly do this, I think you'd have to split the parameter list in 2 parts; the part covered by args (so the first `len(args)` parameters) and the part covered by kwargs. If they overlap (i.e. a key of kwargs is in a position <= `len(args)`), this param has 2 values -> fail. If a required argument has no assigned value (so `len(kwargs) < len(required_kwargs)`), fail as well. Don't forget to manually mark any parameter starting with * as not required (as these are the *args and **kwargs parameters).

This is, however, a rather complex calculation, and your time would probably be better spent using try/except; also efficiencywise, as the function won't run if it lacks arguments.